# how can I send post request in ajax to laravel route parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I want to toggle publish stat of my exams in laravel, I created a route for toggling and it worked, but I don't want to refresh the page every time I send a POST request so I created this function to send,

```
function togglePublish(id){
    let token = {{ csrf_token() }};
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: `{{ route('togglePublish','${id}') }}`,
        data: `_token=${token}`
    });
}
```

I meant by this after the laravel compile the page, the URL will be `https://localhost/toggle/${id}` then javascript change the id variable to `1` for example, so the link be `https://localhost/toggle/1` and that will work, but laravel returned

> Missing required parameter for [Route: togglePublish] [URI: a/togglePublish/{exam}] [Missing parameter: id].

*I think I have to add `@csrf`*

the route

```
Route::post('/a/togglePublish/{exam:id}', [AdminExamController::class, 'togglePublish'])->name('togglePublish');
```

the `togglePublish` function in `AdminExamController` controller

```
public function togglePublish(Exam $exam)
{
    dd($exam);
}
```

Comment: you cannot change `id` dynamically, because `route()` renders url in server by laravel, and your js code executes in client (browser). BTW, if you insist on doing this, there is a library named [ziggy](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy) which may help you.

Comment: You Can Try This -> {{ url('/a/togglePublish/'.${id}) }}

Comment: thank you so much, it worked and I've also modified it, I added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in plus of what @vivekVaghela said, I've changed my ajax to

```
function togglePublish(id){
        let token = '@csrf';
        token = token.substr(42, 40);
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: `{{ url('/a/togglePublish/'.'${id}') }}`,
            data: `_token=${token}`,
            error: function(err) {
                console.log( $($(err.responseText)[1]).text() )
                debugger;
            }
        });
    }
```

**EDIT**: to use ajax you have to use the `uncompressed` script tag, as below

1. JQuery Official website: [Click me](https://code.jquery.com/)
2. Select the version that you need (The latest stable version is recommended) and click on the uncompressed button enter image description here
   [image]
   Copy the script on the dialog box and past it on your code: enter image description here
   [image]

---

res
[TypeError: $.ajax(...) is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69409674/18001301)